# Why are static images not loading in heroku server with nodejs buildpack?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, vite

I have a nodejs express project for backend and a react project for the frontend. There might be a better way to do this, but I build the react project and then serve the build files from the nodejs express server like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

When I run the server locally the images load fine but when I push my changes to github and subsequently deploy the change to Heroku, the images do not load. There are no errors in the console either so I am not able to see what the error is.

```
const app = express();

// admin routes
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

if (config.env !== 'test') {
  app.use(morgan.successHandler);
  app.use(morgan.errorHandler);
}

// set security HTTP headers
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
      'img-src': [
        "'self'",
      ],
    },
  })
);

// parse json request body
app.use(express.json());

// parse urlencoded request body
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// sanitize request data
app.use(xss());
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// gzip compression
app.use(compression());

// enable cors
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

I use this part of the code to serve images, so that I am able to access the image from the mobile app.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

One of the images is working and its the only one that is a jpg. I tried changing a png file to jpg but that still did not work

I checked the paths to the image and I know that heroku can be case sensitive. The paths are fine as one of the images is loading